# A month of Sundays

Tags: idioms

In a month of Sundays is used to emphasize that something will never happen. But this one, A month of Sundays in Paris, this is not the case. How can this be understood?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please provide the full context of the quote, as otherwise it is impossible to say how to understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a common expression; judging from Google, it seems to have been used only once, as the headline of a bbc.com slideshow about Paris in August: http://www.bbc.com/travel/slideshow/20130724-a-month-of-sundays-in-paris

The implication is that, in Paris, the whole month of August is like one extended Sunday: leisurely, no one is at work, no one is in a hurry.

The headline is meant to be clever, using the phrase "a month of Sundays" without its normal idiomatic meaning.

Comment: On the contrary, it's not 'without its normal idiomatic meaning' as I see it. Really, it is with the idiom. The author seems to say the month of August, for all practical purposes, does not exist (as people don't work). The idiom is the soul of the title. :) -- I saw this post just now.

Answer (score 2):

A month of Sundays doesn't mean something will never happen. It is generally just an expression used hyperbolically to indicate a long period of time, since a month of Sundays would be about 30 weeks. See [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/month+of+Sundays), [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/month_of_Sundays) and [here](http://www.yourdictionary.com/month-of-sundays-a#idioms).

Occasionally, it's also used to indicate a period of inactivity or leisure as also key to it's meaning, given the nature of Sundays in the western tradition as a day of rest.

Comment: Yeah, it basically means a period so long that you lose track of how long.  "I haven't seen him in a month of Sundays" is a fairly common usage.